# Fetch Facebook posts using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to retrieve [this information](https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/posts) and show it in our website?

I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/KPzW7/) but no luck, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to `$.getJSON`. As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#notes-0) states, the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

I don't see you mention a language you want to use in order to get those posts, but here are 2 simple examples of how to do it using:

- PHP:

> $info =
>   json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/posts'));
>
> ```
> if ($info) {
>     foreach ($info->data as $obj) {
>         echo $obj->message, "<br/>";
>     }   
> }
> ```

- javascript:

> ```
> <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> FB.api('/cocacola/posts', function(response) {
>     for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
>         alert(response.data[i].message);
>     }
> });
> </script>
> ```

Good luck!