# Facebook Graph API parse JSON feed with PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use php to parse a JSON feed of posts using Facebook Graph API

I found the following solution for comments...

```
<?php 

$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?

ids=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyF-fj-1coY&feature=player_embedded";
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);

$fb_response = json_decode($requests);




foreach ($fb_response as $key => $response) {
  foreach ($fb_response->$key as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
      echo 'NAME: ' . $item->name . '<br />';
      echo 'From ID: ' . $item->from->id . '<br />';
      echo 'From Name: ' . $item->from->name . '<br />';
      echo 'Message: ' . $item->message . '<br />';
      echo 'Timestamp: ' . $item->created_time . '<br /><br />';
    }
  }
} 
    ?>
```

This is the url id I'm working with: https://graph.facebook.com/210849652406/feed/?access_token={VALID_USER_TOKEN}

I just don't know how to call the items for this feed. I'm trying to make the comments parse with this post/feed but I get essentially nothing. I want the basic items like name of the post, caption, etc. I think if I just could get the name of the post I could figure it all out!

Comment: be careful posting usable access_tokens on the web, someone might use it for nefarious purposes.  I edited it out for you

Comment: It's actually from facebook testing so it expires after a while, but that might throw people off anyway, so thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looping incorrectly

try this

```
foreach($fb_response->data as $item){
echo 'Message: ' . $item->message . '<br />';//there is no name returned on a comment
echo 'From ID: ' . $item->from->id . '<br />';
 echo 'From Name: ' . $item->from->name . '<br />';
 echo 'Message: ' . $item->message . '<br />';
 echo 'Timestamp: ' . $item->created_time . '<br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have warnings/errors displayed? Ensure that you have `extension=php_openssl.dll` (or `.so`) enabled in your php.ini or you will get no results. This is because you are fetching from a secure site.

Also `$item->name` is an undefined property in the JSON. Perhaps you mean `$item->id`. Everything else looks ok.

Comment: The code I'm shown does work, however I'm trying to get that code to work for displaying posts or the feed from facebook not the comments from a specific post. The graph url that I'm trying to parse is this: https://graph.facebook.com/210849652406/feed/ + a valid access key

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582535/fetch-facebook-posts-using-graph-api

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using the PHP SDK?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/