# Facebook Graph API: rendering posts like Facebook

Tags: php, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there any public code of PHP/CSS to integrate my Facebook-Posts on my own WebPage in the style of Facebook?

I mean the Step after fetching the Data from the Facebook Graph API ([fetch-facebook-posts-using-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582535/fetch-facebook-posts-using-graph-api))

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite straight-forward to reproduce the same appearance. You might find an inspection/debugging tool like [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) quite helpful.

Basically, open up a Facebook page, inspect a post-box, experiment around (by checking/unchecking styles) to see what each of the style rules does, discard the unnecessary ones and take the ones you need.

Comment: i mean the handling of the different types: music, link, status, video, photo of posts and the caption of it like soundcloud-player inside.

Comment: @hannsworst Then nope, unless you can somehow get Facebook's PHP :)